# pageAnchorBuilder question - Cycle Plugin - JQuery: Changing Image Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using the Cycle plugin for JQuery to create a banner rotator with the pauseOnHover functionality. I have it working properly and even have the pageAnchorBuilder working correctly so that it displays an image vs '1,2,3, etc. The problem is it can't find the images because I am not using images as the selector but divs.

How can I change the following code to let me specify which unique image to display for each slide (div)? When I place the image url (../images/tab.png) in the img src tag it displays a broken link. Even if that was to work it would not accomplish what I am trying to do, display a unique image per div.

I am trying to create a javascript version of something like this: http://www.bazaarvoice.com

Here is my code:

banner.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        speed:      200,
        timeout:    15000, 
        pager:      '#tabs',
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
        pauseOnPagerHover: true,
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i, slide){// callback fn for building anchor links:  function(index, DOMelement) 
    return '<a href="path-to-link"><img src="' + slide.src + '" height="47" width="189" /></a>';
}


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea of what the `pagerAnchorBuilder` function actually is. You should already have the elements in the DOM and be returning the **JQUERY SELECTOR** for those elements, which corresponds to each of the slides (usually by the index passed to the function). View one of the [demos here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager6.html). It may help you get a better understanding of what's going on there.

If you're trying to build a cycle that scrolls through anchors, you have to do nothing more than include your anchor HTML markup inside the (presumably) `div.slidehow`:

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <a href="path-to-link1"><img src="/images/src1.png" height="47" width="189" /></a>
   <a href="path-to-link2"><img src="/images/src2.png" height="47" width="189" /></a>
</div>
```

and the Cycle Plugin will do it for you. There are some [limitations to using images inside anchors](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/anchor.html) with this plugin, though.